# Possible babel latvian and titlesec conflict?

Tags: babel, titlesec, incompatibility

I am writing assignments for university and they have to be in Latvian. I use the babel package as it gives the most appropriate formatting out of the box. It's not enough so I also use titlesec to change the formatting of the sections slightly (different font size, bold and centered).

I discovered that just loading the titlesec and babel package immediately gives errors "Undefined control sequence" and "Missing number, treated as zero" with \section{} but it does not give errors with \section*{}

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[latvian]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

    \section*{First section}
    
    First section text
    
    \section{Second section text}
    
\end{document}
```

Here is the full error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\the@chapter ...ed \relax \else \ifnum \c@chapter 
                                                  >\z@ \thechapter \fi \fi 
l.20     \section{Second section text}
```

**Can the error be prevented at all? How could I circumvent said error while still using latvian babel?**

Comment: Is it an option to use `book` or `report` instead of `article`? There is no error with those two document classes, `chapter` is not defined in the `article` class hence your error I think

Comment: It’s a bug in `titlesec`, which is defining `\chapter` (it shouldn’t). Write `\let\chapter\undefined`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package isn't correctly checking if the class has chapters. Simplest workaround is just to define an unused chapter counter.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[latvian]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcounter{chapter}
\begin{document}

    \section*{First section}
    
    First section text
    
    \section{Second section text}
    
\end{document}
```